# "sqlite3.OperationalError: database or disk is full" on Lustre

Tags: sqlite

I have this error in my application log:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: database or disk is full
```

As plenty of disk space is available and my SQLite database does not appear to be corrupted (`integrity_check` did not report any error), why is this happening and how can I debug it?

I am using the Lustre filesystem (with `flock` set), and until now, it worked perfectly.

Versions are:

- Python 2.6.6
- SQLite 3.3.6

Answer (score 11):

It's probably too late for the original poster, but I just had this problem and couldn't find an answer so I'll document my findings in the hope that it will help others:

As it turns out, an SQLite database actually **can** get full even if there's plenty of disk space, because it has a limit for the *number of pages* in a database file:

http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_max_page_count

In my case the value was 1073741823, which meant that in combination with a page size of 1024 Bytes the database maxed out at 1 TB and returned the "`database or disk is full`" error.

The good news is that you can raise the limit; for example double it by issuing `PRAGMA max_page_count = 2147483646;`.

The limit doesn't seem to be saved in the database file, though, so you have to run it in your application every time you open the database.

Comment: Hello, can you please tell me how to execute the command in windows ?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this multiple times. Even after bumping the page count I get the error when vacuuming but at least now I have a direction to go. I just barely hit this limit at 99% of my data being loaded, too.

Answer (score 4):

By default, SQLite uses `/tmp` temporary directory (not the memory).  If  `/tmp` is too small you will get `disk full`.  In that case change the temporary directory like that:  `export TMPDIR=<big file system>`.

Answer (score -3):

I had same problem too.
Your host or PC's storage is full so delete some files in your system then problem is gone.